# How to sum duplicates in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am creating a [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)chart, which I have done succesfully but I am lot having duplicates.

Below is a sample [xml](/questions/tagged/xml)where I am retrieving data from to display on my Bar chart.

How do I sum the duplicate values retrieved from the [xml](/questions/tagged/xml)?

**[xml](/questions/tagged/xml):**

```
<counts>
    <serial>3123111</serial>
    <scans>3</scans>
    <prints>1</prints>
    <copies>0</copies>
</counts>
<counts>
    <serial>3123111</serial>
    <scans>0</scans>
    <prints>2</prints>
    <copies>0</copies>
</counts>
<counts>
    <serial>AHTSD111</serial>
    <scans>0</scans>
    <prints>1</prints>
    <copies>2</copies>
</counts>
<counts>
    <serial>AHTSD111</serial>
    <scans>0</scans>
    <prints>1</prints>
    <copies>2</copies>
</counts>
```

Expected result below which I use for the barchart:

```
<counts>
    <serial>3123111</serial>
    <scans>3</scans>
    <prints>3</prints>
    <copies>0</copies>
</counts>
<counts>
    <serial>AHTSD111</serial>
    <scans>0</scans>
    <prints>2</prints>
    <copies>4</copies>
</counts>
```

Data retrieved and pushed to the Chart data, I know i have to do a loop to sum the values of scan, prints, copies for each Serial Number but I still keep getting duplicate values, I just left the code out.

$.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost5/api/",
                dataType: 'xml',
                method: "GET",
                success: function (data) {

```
                var parser = new DOMParser();
                var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(data, "text/html");
                data = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("JobCounts");

                var items = [];

                var serial, prints, copies, scans;

                function getAsText(parent, name) {
                    return parent.getElementsByTagName(name)[0].textContent
                }

                function getAsInt(parent, name) {
                    return parseInt(getAsText(parent, name));
                }

                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    items.push({
                        serial: getAsText(data[i], "serial"),
                        prints: getAsInt(data[i], "prints"),
                        copies: getAsInt(data[i], "copies"),
                        scans: getAsInt(data[i], "scans")
                    });


                }

                items = items.reduce((a, c) => {

                    var same = a.find(v => v.serial == c.serial);
                    console.log(same);
                    if (same) {
                        same.prints += c.prints;
                        same.copies += c.copies;
                        same.scans += c.scans;
                    } else {
                        a.push(c);
                    }
                    return a;
                }, []);
```

//  "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js" 
// JS chart library I am using

```
                var chartdata = {
                    labels: serial,
                    title: "Date",

                    datasets: [
                        {
                            label: 'Copies',
                            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,255,0,0.6)',
                            data: copies
                       }
                    ]

                };
                var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

                var options = {
                    responsive: true,
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        position: "top",
                        text: "DashBoard",
                        fontSize: 12,
                        fontColor: "#111"
                    },
                    legend: {
                        display: true,
                        position: "bottom",
                        labels: {
                           fontSize: 9
                        }
                    },
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                                ticks: {
                                    beginAtZero: true

                            }
                        }]
                    }
                };
                var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
                    'type': 'bar',
                    data: chartdata,
                    options : options,
                    "categoryField": "date",
                    "categoryAxis": {
                       "autoGridCount": false,
                       "gridCount": chartdata.length,
                        "gridPosition": "start",
                        "labelRotation": 90,
                        "startOnAxis": false,
                        "title":"Date"
                    }


                });
            },

            error: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Instead of storing the info in 3 different arrays, you can stored it in a single array of objects which will make it easier to merge objects that have the same `serial` number. Also, the example *JSON DATA* looks more like `XML`.

Comment: it is XML. i will try it now

Comment: @trincot **`dataType`:** The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. In this case, should be `dataType: "xml"`.

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez, correct indeed!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of storing the info in 3 different arrays, you can stored it in a single array of objects which will make it easier to merge objects that have the same `serial` number.

Here is what I mean:

```
var items = [];

function getAsText(parent, name){
    return parent.getElementsByTagName(name)[0].textContent
}

function getAsInt(parent, name){
    return parseInt(getAsText(parent, name));
}

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   items.push({serial: getAsText(data[i], "serial"),
               prints: getAsInt(data[i], "prints"),
               copies: getAsInt(data[i], "copies"),
               scans: getAsInt(data[i], "scans")});
}


// Merge items with the same `serial` value;
items = items.reduce((a, c) => {
    var same = a.find(v => v.serial == c.serial);
    if(same){
       same.prints += c.prints;
       same.copies += c.copies;
       same.scans += c.scans;
    }else{
       a.push(c);
    }
    return a;
}, []);
```

Comment: this https://pastebin.com/BGDM8r55 should be way faster (I guess `O(n)` instead of `O(N^2)`?) _disclaimer_ did not actually run the code - but you should get the idea

Comment: @giorgiga The original question does not mention "faster" as being a requirement

Comment: @guest271314 My message was meant as constructive feedback for Titus so that he could maybe improve his/her answer, but that must have been lost in translation somehow :-)

Comment: @giorgiga What do you mean by "improve his/her answer"? Does the current answer not meet the requirement described at OP?

Comment: @Titus // I get [object object] in the BarChart instead of actual values. When log to the console samething, JSON Stringify i get the actual values but not on the barchart.  Why is that please?
var chartdata = {
                        labels: items,
                        title: "DashBoard",    
                   
                        datasets: [
                            {
                                label: 'Copies',
                                backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,255,0,0.6)',
                                data: copies
                            }]
};

Comment: @Kaycee The problem is not evident from the code in your comment. You should create another question and include all the necessary details in order to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Titus I just updated the code with what you showed me and I tried to implement it on my barchart but I just get {object, object] instead of the actual values . my Javascript knowledge is pretty basic.

Comment: @Kaycee I don't know which library you're using to create the chart or what the `items` and `copies` variables represent that is why I've suggested you post a new question which include all the information necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Titus I have updated the full code and I also added the JS chart library I am using . For some reason Stack overflow is giving me a hard time posting a new question

Comment: @Kaycee Try to use `labels: items.reduce((a, c) => {a.push(c.serial); return a;}, [])` and `data: items.reduce((a, c) => {a.push(c.copies); return a;}, [])`.

Comment: @Kaycee I'm glad I could help. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

You can iterate each `counts` element `.children`, `.map()` each `.tagName` and `.textContent` to an object, push the object to an array, iterate the array and increment each `SCANS`, `PRINTS`, and `COPIES` property if `SERIAL` matches.

Convert `JSON` to elements by iterating resulting array using `.forEach()` and `Object.entries()`.

```js
let data = `<counts>
<serial>3123111</serial>
<scans>3</scans>
<prints>1</prints>
<copies>0</copies>
</counts>

<counts>
<serial>3123111</serial>
<scans>0</scans>
<prints>2</prints>
<copies>0</copies>
</counts>

<counts>
<serial>AHTSD111</serial><scans>0</scans><prints>1</prints><copies>2</copies>
</counts>

<counts>
<serial>AHTSD111</serial><scans>0</scans><prints>1</prints><copies>2</copies>
</counts>`;

let parser = new DOMParser();
let xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(data, "text/html");
let res = [];

for (let {counts:{SERIAL, SCANS, COPIES, PRINTS}} of 
    [...xmlDoc.querySelectorAll("counts")]
    .map(el =>
      ({counts:[...el.children]
               .reduce((o, {tagName, textContent}) =>
                 Object.assign(o, {[tagName]:textContent}), {})
       }))) {
  let curr = res.find(({counts:{SERIAL:s}}) => s === SERIAL); 
  if (!curr) {
    res.push({counts:{SERIAL, SCANS, COPIES, PRINTS}})
  } else {
    curr = curr.counts;
    curr.SCANS = +curr.SCANS + +SCANS;
    curr.PRINTS = +curr.PRINTS + +PRINTS;
    curr.COPIES = +curr.COPIES + +COPIES;
  }
}

res.forEach(o => {
  let key = Object.keys(o).pop();
  let parentNode = document.createElement(key);
  Object.entries(o[key])
  .forEach(([tagName, textContent]) => {
    let childNode = document.createElement(tagName)
    childNode.textContent = textContent;
    parentNode.appendChild(childNode);
    parentNode.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    document.body.appendChild(parentNode);
  })
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
})
```